# Change path of input file , comtypes

Tags: python, docx, doc, win32com, comtypes

I wanted to convert a file called 'nored.doc' to 'modred.docx', and I could do it using the following code.

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client
os.getcwd()
in_file = os.path.abspath('/Check/')
out_file = os.path.abspath('modred')

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open('nored.doc')
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=16)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

But the problem is that it requires me to paste the input file in the directory `"C:\\Windows\\system32\"` . How could I possibly get it working if the input file is present in my working directory???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.getcwd()` to get current working directory. Then code will look like this:

```
import sys
import os

import comtypes.client

working_dir = os.getcwd()
#in_file = os.path.abspath(working_dir  + '/Check/')
#out_file = os.path.abspath(working_dir  + '/modred')
out_file = os.path.abspath('modred')

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
#doc = word.Documents.Open('nored.doc')
doc = word.Documents.Open(working_dir  + '/nored.doc')
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=16)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```